# How dissimilar to an existing logo should mine be to avoid copyright issues?

Tags: logo, copyright

Thinking about starting up a small clothing company with the symbol below:

[image: nikes undefeated logo][image: my logo]

But after surfing the web I discovered Nike's undefeated symbol.

Will my design cause copyright issues? How dissimilar should mine be to avoid issues?

Comment: Probably not if you incorporate your title with the tally marks. Using just the tally marks may matter. Is the Nike logo reserved? If it's not then you should be ok.

Comment: It's copyrighted as far as i'm aware @shawn

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here is a trademark attorney. That's really who you need to ask.

Comment: I am not a trademark attorney but from what I have learned the biggest issue when using similar common symbols arises when you are in the same business. See for example how Apple and Apple records started having legal issues once Apple started selling music.

Comment: Cheers for the advice guys, might just keep thinking/creating now to save future potential issues

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: See also: [**Is it plagiarism if my logo looks similar to an existing one?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24979/is-it-plagiarism-if-my-logo-looks-similar-to-an-existing-one) and also maybe [Is there any service where you can check your designed logo against trademarked logos?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/is-there-any-service-where-you-can-check-your-designed-logo-against-trademarked)